# Create folder on remote pc

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to create a folder inside a shared folder on a remote pc using .Net framework?

Context is windows(desktop) applications.

Currently i am using framework 3.5 and VS 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ChrisBint,can you let me know how to do that?

Comment: there's nothing special you need to do AFAIK, just use the full path and if you have permission everything should be golden

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming you have a path and permissions, there is nothing special about creating a folder on a remote computer vs creating one locally.

Answer (score 1):

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"p:\test-delete-this");
```